# how i get the id from a XML file jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

my xml:

```
<stuffs>
<unit id="code">10</unit>
</stuffs>
```

my jquery ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "xml/test.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) {
                   $(xml).find('stuffs').each(function(){

                        ... the code are here ...

                });
             }
```

i'm trying to get the values from `<unit>` using the ID:

```
var unit = $(this).find('unit').attr('id');
var unitIdVal = $("#"+unit).text();
alert(unitIdVal);
```

but, nothing he found.

i dont know if is the same method of a comun jquery stuff's
because i try to get the value direct using

```
var unitIdVal = $("#code").text();
```

but, nothing again.

ty

Comment: How are you loading in your XML?  I suspect that your selectors are being run against the DOM and not your XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector stuff above is wonky to say the least.  You're getting the ID off of an element and then getting that element once again by ID, all within a loop that does nothing for you...

Here's what it needs to be:

```
var unit = $(this).find('unit').attr('id');
var unitIdVal = $("#"+unit, xml).text(); //provide context to your selector
```

I feel dirty even writing this though, and I hope that it'll be used in a different context and this is merely illustrative.

Here's what it should be.  Note the lack of selecting the very same element that you got the ID off of:

```
//....
success: function(xml) {
    var unitIdVal = $(xml).find('unit').text();
}
//....
```

Please read some [helpful tutorials on XML parsing](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery) thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$("#code").text();` looks for the id in the html document.

`$("#code", xmlDoc).text();` should work.

Comment: yeah, this will work, but i need to get the value from the ID, no directly from the tag.